# How can i enable my custom module to allow syndication?

Tags: rss, dotnetnuke

Its an option in the module setting, but when i enable it for my custom module nothing happens, anyone created a module for dot net nuke before that put the content in a RSS feed before?

Answer (score 1):

Builtin RSS support is (or at least was) based on the search results for a module (which are provided via `ISearchable`). [Here](http://blog.coryisakson.com/2005/10/28/RantDotNetNukeISearchable.aspx) is an explanation why `ISearchable` is not very (or at all) useful for search and/or RSS (read the comments though).